# Paypal Integration in Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, paypal

I have a problem in Paypal integration in iOS.

I've read the full documentation, but:

```
[PayPalMobile initializeWithClientIdsForEnvironments:@{PayPalEnvironmentProduction :
 @"",PayPalEnvironmentSandbox : @"YOUR_CLIENT_ID_FOR_SANDBOX"}];
```

How do we find the SAND BOX id for client?

I properly get the Client id but problem is with SANDBOX id for client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are testing Paypal in the Sandbox, use the static AppID value for the Sandbox :

Sandbox Id - **APP-80W284485P519543T**

For detail information read [App Credentails section](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/gs_PayPalAPIs).